# Error in tables numeration: All tables with caption but some numbers missing

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I have a long document with many tables. I was checking the list of tables and observed that the tables were incorrectly numbered, i.e.

Table 3.7 and the next table was Table 3.9. I looked for any table between those but I didn't find nothing. Anyone knows why?. all the tables has caption and are in the table environment.

I'm not using a MWE because is too long

**EDIT:**

I reproduced the error

There is the basic structure of my text with every package that I use (maybe some package is the problem)

As you can see, there is only one table, but it's starting its numeration in 4.2 instead 4.1, the numbering in the previous section was good

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[%
    inline,     
    shortlabels     
]{enumitem}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[%
    font=footnotesize,
    justification=centering,
    figurewithin=section,
    tablewithin=section
]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,  
bibstyle=authoryear,        
giveninits=true,        
maxcitenames=2,         
uniquelist=false,           
sorting=ynt,            
sortcites,              
maxbibnames=99,         
url=false,              
eprint=false,           
dashed=false,           
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[%
noabbrev,
nameinlink
]{cleveref} 
\keepXColumns
\sloppy


\partfont{\centering}
\sectionfont{\raggedright\large\MakeUppercase}
\subsectionfont{\raggedright\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
\subsubsectionfont{\raggedright}
\paragraphfont{\raggedright\normalfont\em}
\setlength{\intextsep}{1.5\baselineskip}

\sectiondot{section}
\sectiondot{subsection}
\sectiondot{subsubsection}
\sectiondot{paragraph}

\setchemformula{radical-space = {0.4em}}

\linespread{1.3}


\assignrefcontextentries[]{*}



%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\section{Sec 1}%
\acresetall
%
\blindtext
%
\section{Sec 2}%
%
\blindtext
%
\section{Sec 3}%
\blindtext
\begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \caption{Table 3.1}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
        \midrule
        A & B & C & D\\
        \midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:3.1}
\end{table}%
%
\section{Sec 4: Atention}%
\acresetall
%
\begin{figure}[htb]
\footnotesize
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
\textbf{Item 1}     & Description \\
\textbf{Item 2}     & Long description \blindtext
\end{tabularx}
\caption{First figure}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Second figure}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{table}[htb]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Wrong numbered table}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\midrule
A & B & C & D\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:4.1}
\end{table}%
%
\begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \caption{Table 2}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
\midrule
A & B & C & D\\
\midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:4.2}
\end{table}%
%
\begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \caption{Table 4}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
        \midrule
        A & B & C & D\\
        \midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:4}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We don't need your complete document, just the smalest possible document to reproduce the error.

Comment: @samcarter I've tryied to reproduce the error, but when I compile the numeration are correct

Comment: I bet you are using longtable inside the table environment.

Comment: Make a copy of your document and remove all unnecessary code. Check that the problem persist. If the problem vanishes at some point, you know you found the interesting part

Comment: @samcarter I posted an edit with the erro, could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `tabularx` within the figure (in combination with the `ltablex` package).

- As a quick hack you could add -1 to the table counter

or

- (my preferred option) use a description for the description:

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
\textbf{Item 1}     & Description \\
\textbf{Item 2}     & Long description\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{First figure}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{description}
\item[Item 1] Description
\item[Item 2] Long description
\end{description}
\caption{First figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Wrong numbered table}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, however I found 2 new mistakes, could you help me? Question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428885/107689

Comment: I won my bet, a hidden longtable ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Very true! Your crystal ball works very well!